# HUD and menu integration for Ubuntu Touch apps

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

Is there a way to move the Tabs into a menu, or the toolbar options into a menu?
It would be nice enough to have the toolbar options display in the menu when on the desktop..  Is there any work to add HUD integration to QML apps... if so where can I find the API?

Answer (score 2):

In QML you can use the [Ubuntu.Components.Action](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.Action/) to define reusable actions that can be used in the [toolbar items](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.ToolbarItems/), as well as the [HUD](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.Page/#tools-prop).

Comment: Thanks for your help!  So will this enable use of the menu bar in the desktop?  I am looking to have the desktop version behave like a desktop app with a menu in the window's title bar (or top panel depending on the user) with a drop down list like a 'normal' desktop app (i.e. file edit help, etc...).  Is this possible yet?  If not will it?